# Error when attempting to add data source to Azure OpenAI api

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, large-language-model, azure-openai

My code is working for a call to Azure OpenAi when I don't have a datasource added. However, when I do add my datasource with the following parameters I get an error:

```
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages = [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "when the user provides a project name as input you should do the steps mentioned below: Step 1: Get the project band of the project from the file."
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": 'Project Name: "Test project" '
        }
    ],
    model = "GPT-3.5 Turbo",
    seed = 42,
    temperature = 0,
    max_tokens = 800,
    extra_body = {
        "dataSources": [
            {
                "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
                "parameters": {
                    "endpoint": os.environ["SEARCH_ENDPOINT"],
                    "key": os.environ["SEARCH_KEY"],
                    "indexName": "test-index"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Gives error:

```
Exception has occurred: BadRequestError
Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Unrecognized request argument supplied: dataSources', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
httpx.HTTPStatusError: Client error '400 model_error' for url 'https://openai-ngap-genai-poc.openai.azure.com//openai/deployments/NTAPOC/chat/completions?api-version=2023-09-01-preview'
For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/400

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\choran\OneDrive - Open Sky Data Systems\Documents\NTA\NTA Chatbot code\Attempting to add datasource.py", line 13, in <module>
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Unrecognized request argument supplied: dataSources', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}

Verified that datasource details were correct.
```

[Full code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rOHS.png)

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Comment: @Colm Horan Check the posted answer, Hope this addressed your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my environment, when I tried the same code, I got the same error:

**Error:**

> openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message':'Unrecognized request argument supplied: dataSources', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}

[image]

You can use this [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/migration?tabs=python-new,dalle-fix#use-your-data) to create your own data with chat completion.

You can use the code below to create chat completion with data source and openai version **`1.9.0`**.

**Code:**

```
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI

endpoint=os.environ["AZURE_ENDPOINT"]
deployment="gpt-35-turbo"
apikey=os.environ["API_KEY"]
client = AzureOpenAI(
    base_url=f"{endpoint}/openai/deployments/{deployment}/extensions", 
    api_key=apikey, 
    api_version="2023-09-01-preview")

for i in range(3):
    print (f'Answer Version {i + 1}\n---')

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model = deployment,
    messages = [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "When the user provides a project name as input, you should do the steps mentioned below: Step 1: Get the project band of the project from the file."
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": 'Where do I go for Azure OpenAI customer support?" '
        }
    ],
    seed = 42,
    temperature = 0,
    max_tokens = 800,
    extra_body = {
        "dataSources": [
            {
                "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
                "parameters": {
                    "endpoint": os.environ["SEARCH_ENDPOINT"],
                     "key": os.environ["SEARCH_KEY"],
                     "indexName": "test-index"
                    }
             }
        ]
    }
)
print (completion.choices[0].message.content) 

print("---\n")
```

**Output:**

```
Answer Version 1
---
Answer Version 2
---
Answer Version 3
---
You can check the Cognitive Services support options guide for help with Azure OpenAI [doc1].
---
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "extra_body" block: your "dataSources" item should be at the same level as messages

Example:
[image]

Comment: Still getting the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 13, in <module>
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\choran\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 271, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Completions.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataSources'
PS C:\Users\choran\OneDrive - Open Sky Data Systems\Documents\NTA\NTA Chatbot code>

Comment: I have added full code to original question